# 12:52:27: Debug: ..\..\include\wx/msw/private.h(697): 'UnregisterClass' failed with error 0x00000584 (class still has open windows.)

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

When building a gui with wxformbuilder for a python program; after a number of edits and re-builds I get the following error:

12:52:27: Debug: ....\include\wx/msw/private.h(697): 'UnregisterClass' failed with error 0x00000584 (class still has open windows.).

What did I do wrong and where do I start troubleshooting it/how do I fix it?

Comment: I had an overlap somewhere in the gui, got it fixed